# IIS7: Set expires header on favicon

Tags: iis-7

I know how to set expires headers for whole directories, but how do I set an expires header for an individual file - e.g. the favicon.ico file in the root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to use a custom developed HttpModule to do this.  Here is a similar question from StackOverflow about this.  It doesn't look like there is anything built in.

[IIS7: Setting far future expires header on specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197168/iis7-setting-far-future-expires-header-on-specific-files)

Comment: Man, in IIS6 it was easy!